# AngularJs post query string to c# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that has to post data to a 3rd party URL. To get around the CORS browser issue, I am posting the data to my .net controller which will then post it to the 3rd party URL. In my javascript file, I've built the query string I want to pass to the 3rd party URL. Here is my code that posts to my .net controller:

```
var parms = "name=john&phone=1234567890&sex=male";
return $http({
                    url: '/UserForm/PostData/',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: parms
                });
```

My c# controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostData(String parms)
{
    return "";
}
```

the parms variable in PostData is null. What do I need to do to pass my querystring string to my controller?

Comment: is this MVC or Web API?

Comment: @user1024941 - did any of the answers solve your problem.  If so mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this? First - why don't you just define all parameters inside the controller post request definition? Second - I guess you have an error in your URL, you don't need the slash after **"/UserForm/PostData"** (If you don't use some custom routing in your MVC of course)

```
$http.post("/UserForm/PostData", { name: "john", phone: "1234567890", sex: "male" }).then(blahblahal....;
```

+

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostData(String name, String phone, String sex)
{
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a WebApi controller, instead of trying to read `parms` as a parameter passed to the action, use `ReadAsString` to read the posted data.  In your example the result should be the same value in your `parms` variable.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostData()
{
    var parms = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    // Submit parms to third-party api.
    return Ok();
}
```

This task is more appropriate for WebApi, but if you need to use an MVC controller, you can read what was posted by reading Request.InputStream:

```
public ActionResult PostData()
{
    string parms;
    using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
         parms = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    // Submit parms to third-party api.
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: that isn't very testable.

Comment: I get the error "system.web.httprequestbase' does not contain a definition for 'content'".

Comment: Seems like you are using MVC instead of WebApi. See changed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostData(System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormDataCollection form)
{
    string name=form.get("name");
    string phone=form.get("phone");
    string sex=form.get("sex");
}
```

Or else you can try this solution too, you just need to add couple of lines.

```
public class PersonData
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string phone { get; set; }
   public string sex { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public string PostData([FromBody]PersonData form)
{
   string name=form.name;
   string phone=form.phone
   string sex=form.sex;
}
```

Comment: This gives the error the "type or namespace name 'Formatting' does not exist in the namespace 'system.net.http'"

I have using System.Net.Http; at the top of my class.

Comment: Have you referenced the System.Net.Http assembly in your project?